# Flutter, AnimatedContainer animation is extremely slow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

AnimatedContainer animation is extremely slow.

Sometimes it responds fastly
but mostly it responds very slow it takes so much loading time like 4-5 seconds.(Android Stduio emulator, actual device)

On other screens, AnimatedContainer definitely responds quickly, but it seems to be slowing down only on certain screens.

the Root Widget has a Stack, and then the AnimatedContainer moving some background using gradient, and then another Animated Container is placed on the Stack. The code is below.

```
Scaffold(
     body:Stack(children: [
         AnimatedContainerA(moving some background using gradient..),
         Column(some widgets..),
         AnimatedContainerB(sometimes it changes the height and width),
       ]
      )
     );
```

the problem is "AnimatedContainerA" is actually working fine

but "AnimatedContainerB" has a super loading that takes time for 4-5 seconds

why is this happen? any advice would be appreciate

Comment: @pskink what do you mean? complete code is too long I guess and minimal code is already posted. I doubt that if two AnimatedContainers on the stack make the other AnimatedContainer responding slow. Do you think they have nothing to do with it?

Comment: @pskink I am sorry I did not get it where is the button?

Comment: sorry for the late I had a trouble with gradle bug now solved. where have you gone

Comment: so did you run the code i posted? do both animations run immediately when you press the red button?

Comment: @pskink yes It animates immediately. but in my case, the AnimatedContainerA is constantly looping for background gradiation because it keeps changing color so I wonder if it is bother (like memory problem) and also there are some Streambuilder for List inside Column()

Comment: well, i gave you minimal working code with stack and two animated containers, as you can see it works just fine - i dont think that anybody will tell you whats wrong in your code without seeing it

Comment: btw what do you mean by *"AnimatedContainerA is constantly looping"*? does it mean that your app is always busy? i mean it is non stop painting new frames?

Comment: @pskink I posted newly I made this few hours ago for testing. thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

I built new project and then I tested it

and two AnimatedContainers on the stack seems no matter.

it works fine.

But on my screen I have some server communications and lists, and there are many bool triggers and a lot of setState accordingly.
I guess it matters.

I can’t find any other reason except for that reason. Because it’s only different from very simple code.